# ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '?' for key 'PRIMARY' with two differents entries

Tags: mysql, utf8mb4

iam triying to import a table from SQLite to MySQL that contains a lot of japanese kanji characters.
The table where i try to insert the data  looks like this:

```
+--------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| literal      | char(10) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| grade        | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| stroke_count | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| freq         | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| jlpt         | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
```

When i try

```
INSERT INTO main VALUES('',NULL,2,NULL,NULL);
```

i got the next error:

```
mysql>
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '?' for key 'PRIMARY'
And if try to look up that entry i get:

select * from main where literal = '';
+---------+-------+--------------+------+------+
| literal | grade | stroke_count | freq | jlpt |
+---------+-------+--------------+------+------+
|       |  NULL |            4 | NULL | NULL |
+---------+-------+--------------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why looking up '' it shows up like ''?

I thought that it may was related with the UTF8 encoding so , i reconfigured all the Db and tables to utf8mb4 following the instructions of this [link](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4).

Here is mysql configuration:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
```

After that nohing changes...any ideas?

Thanks

best regards

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the collation, those two characters might be treated as equivalent.
You could try another collation - utf8mb4_bin, but then you have to take care for lower-casing all the values in your application code to make sure the primary key is case-insensitive.

Alternatively you could lookup the characters you gave in your example in this database (I cannot post more than 2 links, sorry):
http://codepoints.net/

Their UTF Code Points are:
U+20089
U+2000B

Check here for the standard collation maps: http://www.unicode.org/charts/uca/

I could not find those two characters in any Unicode collation maps, but there are many cases with Latin characters with diacritics (e.g. 'Ç' and 'C'), which are defined as equivalents in the utf8 case-insensitive collation maps.

Comment: Another character that is treated equal in utf8mb4 is "ss" and "ß" (eszett).